# Create database schema for questionaire rating system

Tags: sql, database-design

I want to create an application that rates businesses according to some questionnaires that the users will fill in. But I am having some trouble creating the proper schema. The businesses will be of different type and according to the type of the business the questionnaire can be different. The user will rate the business answering to the questions of the questionnaire from 1-7 whilst different questionnaires can have different number of questions

So my initial thought was the following:

1. Table for Questions
2. Table for Questionnaires with Foreign Key to Questions
3. Table for Businesses

for the questionnaires and businesses. But I can't seem to properly implement the Rating system for each users rating. Is this the right approach? Maybe something different? What are your suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered modelling the information that is the *subject* of the questionnaire rather than the questionnaire itself? A questionnaire is simply a tool for populating that information and doesn't really require a special data model to support it.

Comment: Would you be kind to explain some more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - keep going.  you should also consider:

1. Table to link Business to the Questionnaire that will be asked. (FK to Business and Questionnaire)
2. Table to link the specific Business / questionnaire to a set of answers (per user)

you should then be able to calculate any rating you wish either by business or user or questionnaire

Comment: I was thinking of a Table Answers with columns
UserID, BuisnessID, QuestionID, Rate. QuestionsID can be retrieved from the table no1 that links Buisnesses and Questionaires. What do you think?

Comment: yes. you can break out individual answers especially if the same question is repeated on different questionnaires.